# In Heroku's add-on of Sendgrid, how come I don't have to enter TXT fieldn in my DNS records?

Tags: email, postfix, spam, heroku, sendgrid

When I used Amazon SES, I had to put TXT records in my DNS so that Yahoo/Gmail knows that the server is allowed to send from my domain name.

However, when I signed up for Heroku and Sendgrid Add-on (Free edition), I was not required to enter any TXT fields.  Why?

How does Gmail know that Sendgrid is "authorized" to send on behalf of my domain name if I do not enter records in DNS?

As of right now, I could send `From: hello@paypal.com` using Sendgrid??

Comment: You need to read up on [how SPF records work](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786)...

Comment: Can you explain then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SendGrid's Free accounts do not require any DNS changes [because they set the return path header, SPF, and DomainKeys headers to point to SendGrid's SPF and DomainKeys](http://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/why_dont_i_need_an_spf_record_or_other_dns_mods).  The mails "you" send appear to be coming from SendGrid for the purposes of SPF and DomainKeys and of course SendGrid has that stuff already set up.